# Check null in Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

```
string password = Infoware.Students.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.AdmissionNo == AdmissionNo && x.AdmissionNo != null).Password;
```

Here students is a table where I have AdmissionNo and Password columns, Need to get password if admissionNo exists in the table. This expression is fetching Password for given AdmissionNo if the admissionNo is present in the records but if the entered admissionNo is not found in the records then it throwing NullReference Exception.

How can I check that given AdmissionNo is not a Valid AdmissionNO ??

Comment: use simple if statement.

Comment: Calling `FirstOrDefault().Something` is never a good idea. `FirstOrDefault()` (by design) is expressing that `null` can be returned (for reference types), hence has to be checked first.

Comment: In our project, we made the Id's of objects that are not yet saved in the database <=0. If you can't do that, I'd suggest var x=FirstOrDefault(); password=x==null?null:x.Password

Comment: The (in the latest edit) described behavior is expected. FirstOrDefault() will return the first object that matches the condition, or, if none exists, return null. You might want to look at NullReferenceException definition. Also, your check for x.AdmissionNo!=null is not accomplishing anything at all. objects with AdmissionNo==null will fail comparison with AdmissionNo anyways and won't be returned, or if you're passing in AdmissionNo==null you'll always get null as a return value.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put your tests the other way around (as they will shortcut):

```
string password = Infoware.Students.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.AdmissionNo != null 
                                  && x.AdmissionNo == AdmissionNo ).Password;
```

And re-reading your question, you issue is when nothing is found...

So:

```
string password;

var result = Infoware.Students.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.AdmissionNo != null 
                                      && x.AdmissionNo == AdmissionNo );


if (result != null) {
    password = result.Password;
}
```

Comment: this won't work. objects with admissionNo==null won't be returned by x.AdmissionNo=AdmissionNo anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for null using an if statement"

```
if ( AdmissionNo != null )
{
  //your code
}
```

You can also check [ObjectContextOptions.UseCSharpNullComparisonBehavior Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontextoptions.usecsharpnullcomparisonbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx) which was introduced in EF 5.0

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using Any:

```
.Any(a => a.AdmissionNo == null)
```

Or using if statement:

```
string user = Infoware.Students.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.AdmissionNo == AdmissionNo && x.AdmissionNo != null);
if(user  != null)
{
    password = user.Password;
}
```